# How do I get checked items from multiselect QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I was able to implement multi-select using the QComboBox and QStandardItemModel, but I am not able to get the selected items using the selectedItems() or checkedItems() options which is giving an error message displayed as:

```
AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'selectedItems'               
AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'checkedItems'
```

Is there a way to get a list of selected items for the QComboBox? 
Below is the example implementation of my code

```
class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

class Dialog_01(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow,self).__init__()       
        years = ["2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
        self.comboBoxv = QComboBox(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("Select  Years")
        firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
        firstItem.setSelectable(False)
        self.model.setItem(0, 0, firstItem)
        for i,area in enumerate(years):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(area)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self.model.setItem(i+1, 0, item)
        self.comboBoxv.setModel(self.model)        
        self.comboBoxv.installEventFilter(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: how can i add my code in here?

Comment: review the [tour]

Comment: I've tried inserting code between ` ` but, its not letting me add comment saying too many characters

Comment: the relevant information such as the code should not be in the comments but in your question, so edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: added the code in my question, thanks ^

Comment: I have questions about your code: 1) are you using PyQt4 or PyQt5? 2) I see that you have declared the class CheckableComboBox but I do not see that you use that class, the QComboBox that is displayed in the window is not the CheckableComboBox. 3) When do you want to get checked items?

Comment: I am using PyQt5, yes, regarding the checkable combo box class I havent been able to implement that class. I am trying to get a list of selected items once the drop down is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkedItems method does not exist, therefore you get that error. The solution is to iterate over the model and verify if it is checked or not.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    closedPopup = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setView(QtWidgets.QListView(self))
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

        firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("Select  Years")
        firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
        firstItem.setSelectable(False)
        self.model().appendRow(firstItem)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    def checkedItems(self):
        l = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            it = self.model().item(i)
            if it.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                l.append(it.text())
        return l

    def hidePopup(self):
        self.closedPopup.emit()
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).hidePopup()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.setCurrentIndex(0))

class Dialog_01(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog_01,self).__init__()       
        years = ["2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
        self.comboBoxv = CheckableComboBox()
        self.comboBoxv.closedPopup.connect(self.on_closedPopup)
        for i, area in enumerate(years):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(area)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.comboBoxv.model().appendRow(item)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.comboBoxv)
        lay.addStretch()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_closedPopup(self):
        print(self.comboBoxv.checkedItems())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is great, I was wondering why doesn't the dropdown stay down until I select items rather than closing every time I select?

Comment: @user9529330 Because the behavior of the ComboBox is only to choose a single element, if you want it not to do it then you must modify that behavior and as you did not point it out I did not want to change it, when do you want the popup to close?

Comment: it will be nice if the popup closes after i am able to select few items and click back on the dropdown.

Comment: @user9529330 The click is used to check an item, how does the click to check and close compare?

Comment: i mean i'd like the dropdown to stay down for me to select more than 1 item

Comment: @user9529330 I understand that, but this leads to asking when do you want the popup to close? Do you want it to close after choosing 2 elements, 1000 elements, ever?

Comment: regardless of the number of elements, if the popup closes after i click outside the qcombobox should work, also, i just realized that items are not selected if i click on the checkbox but rather on the string, not sure if this same on your end too

Comment: @user9529330 Okay, but that was not in your question so I would recommend creating a new question indicating what you have tried and the community will help you. On the other hand if my answer resolved your question then you could mark my answer as correct.

Comment: appreciate your help